# Wildcards at different positions, unexpected Sequential Scan instead of an Index Scan

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, wildcard

**Description:**

I have a table `tickets`. It has a primary key `ticket_no` which is a `varchar`. Because it´s a primary key, it also has an index. I have two simple queries using wildcards and was surprised by the measured performance result and i can´t explain it. I am using a postgres database.

1.) Query with wildcard at the end of the string:

`SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticket_no LIKE '000543200099%';`

2.) Query with wildcard at the start of the string:

`SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticket_no LIKE '%005432000998';`

**Expectations:**

I thought that the execution time of the first query with the wildcard at the end would be much faster, because the attribute has an index and an **Index Scan** could be made in order to find all entries matching the wildcardstring.
The second query has to be slower, because with the wildcard at the beginning all the entires of the table have to be checked with a **Sequence Scan** which would be obviously slower than an **Index Scan**.

**Result:**

It turned out that both queries are equally fast. Checking the sequence diagram it turns out that a **Sequence Scan** was made for **both** queries. I don´t really understand why the **Sequence Scan** is done for the first query instead of an **Index Scan**. Why might that be the case?

**Edit:**

Heres the DDL for the table:

```
create table if not exists tickets
(
    ticket_no varchar not null
        constraint tickets_pkey
            primary key,
    book_ref char(6) not null
        constraint tickets_book_ref_fkey
            references bookings,
    passenger_id varchar(20) not null,
    passenger_name text not null,
    contact_data jsonb
)
```

And for the index:

```
create unique index if not exists tickets_pkey
    on tickets (ticket_no);
```

And heres the EXPLAIN ANAYLZE for both queries, as you see besides marginal time differences they are identical:

1.)

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticket_no LIKE '000543200099%';`

=>

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..67253.74 rows=14749 width=122) (actual time=0.748..219.487 rows=10 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tickets  (cost=0.00..64778.84 rows=6145 width=122) (actual time=128.056..199.550 rows=3 loops=3)
        Filter: ((ticket_no)::text ~~ '000543200099%'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 983282
Planning Time: 1.182 ms
Execution Time: 219.512 ms
```

2.)

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ticket_no LIKE '%005432000998';`

=>

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..65808.34 rows=295 width=122) (actual time=0.768..276.445 rows=1 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tickets  (cost=0.00..64778.84 rows=123 width=122) (actual time=133.961..224.468 rows=0 loops=3)
        Filter: ((ticket_no)::text ~~ '%005432000998'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 983285
Planning Time: 0.117 ms
Execution Time: 276.460 ms
```

Comment: How many rows does the table have? If the table is small (less than 10k rows) a sequential heap scan is usually faster than an index range scan, and PostgreSQL knows it. Even faster if the heap blocks are hot.

Comment: It has a couple of million entries (probably like 5 million).

Comment: Please post table and indexes DDL and EXPLAIN ANALYZE output of both queries.

Comment: Interesting. A couple of other questions, then. What percentage of the rows is selected by query #1? Are the table stats (histogram) up to date?

Comment: I edited my original post and added the DDL for the table and indexes and also showed the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output for both queries.


@TheImpaler Only < 0.1% of the rows are selected by the query #1. But i tried modifying it for it to return > 10% of the rows, but it still behaves the same way (sequential scan).

Comment: @jjanes I tried to use the `collate "C"` approach metioned in that thread but that didn´t help either. `SELECT ticket_no collate "C"  FROM tickets WHERE ticket_no LIKE '000543200099%';` still results in a sequence scan.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to work.  The index needs to be built in that collation, you can't just change it in the query alone.

Comment: Ah okay, so yes i managed to make it work with both answers listed in the mentioned thread. The query #1 correctly uses an index scan now and is 10 times faster now. So should i build every index i plan on using wildcard operators on with `text_pattern_ops` to increase its performance?

Comment: Yes.  Although I just make my whole database use the C collation by default (at the time time the database is created).  It promotes index usage, it makes sorting faster than other collations, and it protects against bugs/changes in glibc's ideas of how collations work.  I sometimes get complaints about the sort order, but they are usually about aspects that a different collation would not fix anyway.

Comment: Ok so from further testing it seems like that only helps to improve the performance if the query selects < 10% of the total amount of rows. If its larger than that postgres still does a sequential scan, because from what i understood that´s faster than an index scan because it needs less I/O operations. So the index doesn´t help at all if the result returns a large amount of the total rows?

Comment: @M.Dietz Yes, that's normal planner behavior. Make sure your table is vacuumed and analyzed so the planner has the most up to date statistics to make its decisions.